# Is there a way to loop through the creation of dataclass entries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass which stores information about beams.  I have the information about the beams in a .csv file which I am reading into a dictionary.

I then want to read the information stored in the dictionary into the dataclass.  I want to loop this so that on each loop iteration a new dataclass is created with a name currently stored in the dictionary and the dataclass is filled with data currently stored in the dictionary.

my dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class FrameElement:
    # attributes to be passed in to define specific instance
    label: str # name
    orient: str # element orientation
    A: float # cross-sectional area
    E: float # young's modulus
    I: float # second moment of area / moment of inertia
    Qfef: float # element fixed end forces (local coord.)
    node1: float # [x-coord., y-coord., x-map., y-map., m-map.]
    node2: float # "
```

the code I'm trying to use to loop the dataclass creation:

```
for i in range(nelem):
    i += 1
    name = 'elem%d'%i
    
    [label, orient, A, E, I, Qfef, node1_str, node2_str, node1_ary, node2_ary] = elem_dict[name]
    
    'elem%d'%i = FrameElement(label, orient, A, E, I, Qfef, node1_ary, node2_ary)
```

I tried to used 'elem%d'%i to create the name for the dataclass entry and then fill it with the information stored in the dictionary.  This returned the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-23-ff5da982294c>", line 7
    'elem%d'%i = FrameElement(label, orient, A, E, I, Qfef, node1_ary, node2_ary)
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
```

Comment: Creating variables dynamically is generally a bad idea. Store the data objects in a dictionary instead.

Comment: you have `name = 'elem%d'%i` already, so why do you try `'elem%d'%i` later? you can just use `name = ...`, *if* that is truly what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dictionary that stores the data then to create the dataclasses you can simple do:

```py
my_dict = {} # that's your source data
dataclass_dict = {}  # output dictionary with dataclasses as values
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    dataclass_dict[k] = FrameElement(*v)
```

This is of course pretty dangerous and relies on the fact that in your source data all the values will maintain their positions in the array.

A better solution would be to have your source data as a dict of dicts where the first dict would have keys as the names of elements and its values would be dictionary of element properties like so:

```
dict_el = {
    'element_1': {
        'label': 'Foo',
        'orient': '',
        ...
        }
    }
```

Then you can do the same as above but be much more confident that you won't have issues:

```
dataclass_dict = {k: FrameElement(**v) for k, v in dict_el.items()}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did to create the variable names:

```
myElements = []

for i in range(nelem):
    i += 1
    name = 'elem%d'%i
    
    [label, orient, A, E, I, Qfef, node1_str, node2_str, node1_ary, node2_ary] = elem_dict[name]
    
    locals()[name] = FrameElement(label, orient, A, E, I, Qfef, node1_ary, node2_ary)
    
    myElements.append(name)
    
print(myElements)
```